# How to resolve 'string contains untranslatable character' while using XMLAGG in Teradata

Tags: sql, xml, character, teradata

I am trying to use XMLAGG to transpose the row-wise data to comma separated value in Teradata 15.
Its working fine with English characters. But while I am using other characters (unicode character set) I am getting '*string contains untranslatable character*' error.

Please suggest how to resolve the issue.

Below is the code.

```
CREATE SET TABLE rv ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      coll INTEGER,
      val VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET unicode NOT CASESPECIFIC)
PRIMARY INDEX ( coll );

insert into rv(1,'test 1');
insert into rv(1,'test 10');
insert into rv(2,'test 2');
insert into rv(2,'test 20');
insert into rv(3,'และ43831'); -- because of this row I am getting error, If we remove it below query is working fine.

  sel coll,TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM (XMLAGG(TRIM(val)|| ',' ORDER BY 1 desc) (VARCHAR(1000))))as Test_Id
 from rv group by 1
```

Comment: What's your exact Teradata release? Works for me as-is on a TD15. Try adding UNICODE: `(VARCHAR(1000), CHARACTER SET UNICODE)`. Is this your actual query?

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks it worked now. I was not using comma before CHARACTER SET UNICODE. So, it was giving error.